# How to configure external config file in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an application in which all configuration like connection string, 
app-setting etc present in my web.config file. In the production environment, when I change some setting. I have to restart the application. I read somewhere that if we add external config file and add it's reference in web.config then we don't need to restart the application. Here is my web.config:

```
 <appSettings configSource="appSettingConfig.xml" />
```

Here is my external config file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="IsShowReportEnabled" value ="True"/>
    <add key="SendReportToPrinter" value ="False"/>
  </appSettings>
```

The external config file is working fine but the problem remains same that if I change in the external file I have to restart the application.
Then i googled and found that add section to configure restart on external file or not. Here it is in web.config:

```
<section name='rewrite' type='???' restartOnExternalChanges='false' />
```

But this also did not help. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228245%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 ? Especially: restartOnExternalChanges - Does not apply to ASP.NET applications.

Comment: Just  read it that restartOnExternalChanges does not apply on asp.net application

Comment: Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: But in this article. It says we can do this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228058.aspx

Comment: you can do it programatically using app.domain

Comment: Can you please share in link for help

Answer (score 0):

> Can any one tell me what i am doing wrong?

Web.config settings are intended to be application-wide settings that are loaded at application startup. Typically, these settings are changed manually or by the deployment process so it is an acceptable side-effect that the application will restart when they are changed.

Runtime settings are not meant to be stored in the `Web.config` file. They are typically stored in another persistent location such as a text file or more commonly, in a database.

Your setting names (in particular `SendReportToPrinter`) sound like they are user-specific settings, not application-wide settings. I would expect these to be stored in a user-specific table in a database, since they would probably need to be different for every user.

Comment: I agreed with you but for client request i have to do this. Is there any way to change without application start?

Comment: No. Changing web.config always restarts the app because the settings are cached within the app. But I re-read your question and it sounds like you are building a multi-tenant app. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32661858) and [How to design a Multi-tenant application with ASP.NET MVC](https://www.appseconnect.com/how-to-design-a-multi-tenant-application-with-asp-net-mvc/) for a couple of approaches how to do it.